# Spotbugs/findbugs collaborating object May expose internal representation by incorporating reference to mutable object

Tags: java, spotbugs

I am trying to setup spotbugs reporting. And I have bug reports for some of the mutable collaborators. Below is a simple example of a utility wrapper over some library object (Here it is a Map but could be something more complicated). And mutating the referenced object is what is intended. Would would be the correct approach in this situation ?

Btw, most of the beans injected by spring also are potentially mutable and vulnerable to the exactly same malicious code but there is no warning on injection.

```java
    package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Map;

public class SomeWrapper {

    private static final String BUSINESS_ID_KEY = "business id key";
    private Map<String, String> impl;

    public SomeWrapper(Map<String, String > impl) {
        this.impl = impl;   //  Bug type EI_EXPOSE_REP2
        //may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into SomeWrapper.impl
    }

    public Map<String, String> getImpl() {
        return impl;//Bug type EI_EXPOSE_REP
        //may expose internal representation by returning SomeWrapper.impl
    }

    public String getBusinessId() {
        return impl.get(BUSINESS_ID_KEY);
    }
    public String setBusinessId(String value) {
        return impl.put(BUSINESS_ID_KEY,value);
    }
    
}
```